# how to lock the screen programmatically in windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

We can prevent the screen to lock using the below code

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.ApplicationIdleMode = IdleDetectionMode.Disabled
```

and

```
PhoneApplicationService.Current.UserIdleDetectionMode= IdleDetectionMode.Disabled
```

but how to lock the screen from my app. Like the below app

http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/store/app/one-touch-lockscreen/a3b1220b-1f9a-4bf0-93bc-21ed02792279

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

It's pretty hacky. It's not in the official API, so it could stop working at any time, just like the volume control API. Anyway, it you want to do it, you need to use this external method:

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("ShellChromeAPI.dll")]
private extern static void Shell_TurnScreenOn(bool value);
```

For WP8.0 app this needs to be in a Windows Runtime Component (you should reference its output, as the project cannot be referenced).

From what I understand, though, this won't work on WP8.1 devices, so you'll need a separate WP8.1 app and I think it needs to be a XAML (Windows Store) app.

Comment: Actually it does work for me in WP8.1, and Windows Runtime Component is not required when I test it. O.O (Is it because that I am using GDR1/2?).

Answer (score 2):

What @yasen wrote is correct.

```
[DllImport("ShellChromeAPI.dll")]
private extern static void Shell_TurnScreenOn(bool value);
```

I've tried the following cases:
Runtime 8.1 C# (Passed store certification)
Runtime 8.1 C++ with Runtime Component 8.1 C# (Haven't tried to publish this in store)
Silverlight/DirectX 8.0 C++ (Passed store certification)

Here's the link to my app that's using the last solution mentioned above.
http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=38bf5918-025e-4f23-b515-2cac451a84ab

And I've heard about cases in store using Silverlight that supports 8.0 and 8.1.

Comment: Submitted a c# 8.1 RT some hours ago, didn't passed certification: •Error Found: The supported APIs test detected the following errors:◦This API is not supported for this application type - Api=Shell_TurnScreenOn. Module=shellchromeapi.dll.

Comment: Are you still using it for you app or you found a workaround?

Comment: @the_nuts I've never updated the app since, though it's still in the store and working.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Screen is locked or not by `Windows.Phone.System.SystemProtection.ScreenLocked`

but Unfortunately There is `no way` to lock the screen via code in `Windows Phone 7.x or 8.`