# Programatically lock screen windows phone 8

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, screen-lock

I am making an app in VS2012 c# language. I need a help.
I want to lock screen of the windows phone on an button click event.
I went through many documented APIs but I am not able to find this code anywhere.

Kindly guide me.
Thanking you

Comment: that contains definition to change lock screen background and lock screen notifications. I want to "Lock" on button click.

Comment: Already discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959975/how-to-lock-the-screen-programmatically-in-windows-phone-8).

Answer (score 1):

There are currently `no API's that will allow you to turn on lockscreen programmatically` in Windows Phone application.

Comment: No **official** API's you mean. There are apps that do it as you may know, so it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can find something in this thread: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2594420

Comment: +1 I fail to understand how the only actual answer has less points than the others. You could've given the useful info from that page in the answer, though.

Answer (score 1):

You can get Screen is locked or not by `Windows.Phone.System.SystemProtection.ScreenLocked`

but Unfortunately There is `no way` to lock the screen via code in `Windows Phone 7.x or 8`.

Comment: By "no way" you mean "no official way", right? There are apps that do it, as you may know.